# How to use locks to prevent a race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a bug in my code which I have identified to be a race condition. I know it is a race condition, because it occurs intermittently. I have researched how to prevent these race conditions and I came across this

```
      for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
      {
           //lock x
           x = x + 1; 
           //unlock x
      }
```

Could somebody please go into further detail on how I may implements these locks?

Comment: If you are using `pthread`s, then you may use `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`

Comment: The simplest way, if you have C++11, is `std::atomic<int> x;`.

Answer (score 4):

Your example suggest, that all you want to do in your threads is an operation on an int variable. If that is really the case then, as others pointed out, `std::atomic` is probably the easiest way to implement it.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic<int> x = 0;

void increment()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    {
        ++x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(increment);
    std::thread t2(increment);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << x;
}
```

However, to protect more complicated operations from being executed in multiple threads simultaneously, you should use [`std::lock_guard`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/lock_guard/?kw=lock_guard). It uses the RAII (resource acquisition is initialization) principle to lock a mutex for its lifetime.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

int x = 0;
std::mutex mtx;

void increment()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); //lock mtx
        ++x;

        // mtx is automatically released when lock
        // goes out of scope -> RAII
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(increment);
    std::thread t2(increment);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << x;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments here is another example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    void increment()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); //lock mtx
            ++x;

            // mtx is automatically released when lock
            // goes out of scope -> RAII
        }
    }

    void decrement()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); //lock mtx
            --x;

            // mtx is automatically released when lock
            // goes out of scope -> RAII
        }
    }

    static int x;
    static std::mutex mtx;
};

int Foo::x = 0;
std::mutex Foo::mtx;

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(&Foo::increment, Foo());
    std::thread t2(&Foo::decrement, Foo());

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << Foo::x;
}
```

Comment: If the variable is within a object member function, can I still implement this code?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Maybe you can edit your question with a small example? However, if your variable is a local variable in some member function then I hardly doubt that your problem is a race condition regarding this variable.

Comment: I have a static variable that is accessed by two different functions within the same object.  However sometimes the second function skips this variable altogether

Comment: If the variable type can be used with `std::atomic` then simply change its declaration and make it use `std::atomic`. If you want to go for the mutex solution, then add another static variable of type std::mutex to your class and make sure both member functions construct a `std::lock_guard` before accessing it.

Comment: I Added another example which should suit your use-case

Comment: Great example on using mutexes

Answer (score 2):

> I know it is a race condition, because it occurs intermittently

While race conditions typically do occur intermittently, there are other kinds of bugs that have similar behaviour, so your reasoning isn't guaranteed to be accurate. That said, without seeing the program, sure that is a very likely problem in a program with multiple threads.

> Could somebody please go into further detail on how I may implements these locks?

A mutual exclusion lock can not be implemented in C++. They are typically implemented using a machine instruction [Test-and-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set).

You don't need to implement a lock yourself however. Since C++11, the standard library already contains an implementation. Even better, it contains higher level atomic types (`std::atomic`), that provide atomic access without explicitly locking the execution (the implementation of atomic types may even use more efficient instructions that avoid locking, depending on target architechture).

If your standard library is outdated, then you can use the threading API provided by your operating system. It most almost definitely provides you with some sort of *mutex* structure.